# How do you allow only numbers, backspace, and hyphens in a text box in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

```
If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back AndAlso e.Keychar = "-" Then
    e.Handled = True
```

I can't seem to get the code working. I am trying to only include the Text Box to enter numbers, backspace, and hyphens working, but hyphens are not working, other work. Help?

Comment: You already asked this question.  Repeating: last operand must be `<>` instead of `=`.

Comment: Just to emphasize what @HansPassant says. Instead of **AndAlso e.Keychar = "-"** use **AndAlso e.Keychar <> "-"**

Comment: Ok thanks you really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a MaskedTextBox. It's a pretty useful control.  Without any extra coding it allows you to specify what characters are allowed in the textbox, which I think  is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10816601)

Comment: I edited my answer to make it a bit "friendlier" but it actually does provide a solution to the OP's problem. And a cleaner one than writing extra code which is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score -1):

This is always a pain, and quite a common question. My usual way of managing this is to utilise the KeyPress event as so:-

```
    Private Sub nudInsertFTS_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles nudInsertFTS.KeyPress, nudInsertTS.KeyPress, nudInsertFTL.KeyPress, nudInsertTL.KeyPress, nudInsertTTS.KeyPress, nudInsertTTL.KeyPress
    ' Reset The Timer
    Functions.ResetTimer()
    'If certain characters then allow
    If e.KeyChar = vbBack Then Exit Sub
    ' do not allow the comma character (or any other invalid characters)
    If e.KeyChar = "." Or e.KeyChar = "-" Or IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) = False Then e.KeyChar = Chr(0)

End Sub
```

Ignore the Function.ResetTimer - this is a function to prevent the application from shutting down. My customer wants the application to shutdown after 10 minutes of inactivity.